# $.ajax datatype:json throws error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm  trying to retrieve a json object through a ajax request from a php file. My ajax request looks like the following:

```
function validateForm() {
var name = $('#usernameLogIn').val();
var password = $('#passwordLogIn').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../webroot/login/validateForm/',
    data: {name: name, password: password},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(result);
    var b = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(b);

        },
        error: function(a,b,c) { console.log(a,b,c); }
  });
}
```

and my php file looks like this:

```
$form = $this->form; 
      $status = false;
      $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_GET['name']);
      $formPassword = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_GET['password']);
      $now = date(DATE_RFC2822); 
      $user =  $this->user->findName($name); 

      if(isset($user->name))
      {
        $password = $user->password;
        $status = password_verify($formPassword, $password);
      }

      if ($status === true) 
      { 
         $this->session->set('loggedIn', $this->user->name);
      } 

      else if ($status === false) { 

          $this->session->clearSession('loggedIn');
    }

      $sessionLog = $this->session->get('loggedIn');

      $advert = array(
    'session' => $sessionLog,
    'name' => $name,
    'password' => $formPassword,
 );

echo json_encode($advert);
exit;
```

Finally when it passes the values back to my Ajax request it goes straight into the error function and prints the following into the console:

```
Object "parsererror" SyntaxError
message: Unexpected Token <"
```

Is it any way to tell where this goes wrong and why?

thankfull for answers, cheers.

Comment: The response isn't JSON. Look in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools to see what it actually is.

Comment: You have a 501 Error my friend

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify` and then immediately calling `JSON.parse` on that? You could just write `var b = result;` and get the same effect.

Comment: so if i understand correctly the error lies within my php file since the response isn't JSON? Isnt this how you return JSON: echo json_encode($advert);?

Comment: Yes. It's probably getting an error, and the error message is being sent in the AJAX response, in addition to or instead of the JSON.

Comment: As @Quentin said, go to DevTools/Firebug and view the raw response. You'll probably see the error message there.

Comment: AH sorry guys. I had verbose set to true in my sql config file which printed out raw html with sql commands before my json data. Thanks for your guidance though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have verbose set to true in you config file.